# Troubles with code for login on Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, dao

I am new to VB Scripting and Scripting of any kind but I am a fast learner.

I have with the help of various aids been developing an Access database where scripting is used.

I have developed the below script as part of a login screen.

```
Private Sub cmdLogin_Click()

    Dim dbs As Database
    Dim rstUserPwd As Recordset
    Dim bFoundMatch As Boolean

    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Set rstUserPwd = dbs.OpenRecordset("qryUserPwd")

    bFoundMatch = False

    If rstUserPwd.RecordCount > 0 Then
        rstUserPwd.MoveFirst

        ' check for matching records
        Do While rstUserPwd.EOF = True
            If rstUserPwd![UserName] = frmLogin.txtUsername.Value And rstUserPwd![Password] = frmLogin.txtPassword.Value Then
                bFoundMatch = True
                Exit Do
            End If
            rstUserPwd.MoveNext
        Loop

    End If

    If bFoundMatch = True Then
        'Open the next form here and close this one
        DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmNavigation"

    Else
        '
        MsgBox "Incorrect Username or Password"

    End If

    rstUserPwd.Close

End Sub
```

Even though I enter the correct username and password I get the "Incorrect Username or Password message pop up. Can anyone help by telling me what I have done wrong please. If needed I can add a copy of the database.

Comment: @PankajJaju That is [tag:VBA] method used in MS Access to denote the currently opened database in [tag:DAO]. See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221178(v=office.11).aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

Carefully consider the logic in this line ...

```vb
Do While rstUserPwd.EOF = True
```

That says to VBA, *"run the code in this block while the condition is True"*.  However, when you first encounter that line, your recordset's current row is the first row (as a result of `MoveFirst`).  And therefore `EOF` is False, and since False is not equal to True, the code in the `Do While` loop is not run.

My first guess is you want something like this to control the loop.

```vb
Do While Not rstUserPwd.EOF
```

That change might get your code working as you intend.  However that approach is more complicated than necessary.  Instead of opening a recordset and walking the rows to check for a user name and password match, you could use a [DCount](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/dcount-function-HA001228817.aspx) expression.

Answer (score 0):

I asume the username and password are both string values and would suggest changing your code as following:

```
Dim sSql As String
Dim rstUserPwd As DAO.Recordset
Dim bFoundMatch As Boolean

sSql = "Select * from qryUserPwd Where UserName='" & Nz(frmLogin.txtUsername, "") & "' And Password = '" & Nz(frmLogin.txtPassword, "") & "'"
Set rstUserPwd = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sSql, dbOpenSnapshot)

If Not (rstUserPwd.BOF And rstUserPwd.EOF) Then
    bFoundMatch = True
End If
rstUserPwd.Close: Set rstUserPwd = Nothing


If bFoundMatch = True Then
    'Open the next form here and close this one
    DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmNavigation"

Else
    '
    MsgBox "Incorrect Username or Password"

End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use this 1 liner:

```
bFoundMatch =  DCount("*", "qryUserPwd", "UserName = '" & frmLogin.txtUsername & "' And Password = '" & frmLogin.txtPassword & "'") > 0
```